# How is nested embeds_many handled with mongoid in the following situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

for example I have three models i.e, modelA, modelB, and modelC

```
class ModelA
  embeds_many :modelBs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :modelBs
end

class ModelB
  embedded_in :modelA
  embeds_many :modelCs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :modelBs
end

class ModelC
  embedded_in :modelB
end
```

And I am trying to create all three models from one controller i.e., ModelAcontroller. How do I do that in mongoid? In active record, simply stating accepts_nested_attributes_for does the job.

Comment: Should work the same way in Mongoid. https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-nested-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

First, include Mongoid::Document

```
class ModelA
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :modelBs
end

class ModelB
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :modelA
  embeds_many :modelCs
end

class ModelC
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :modelB
end
```

You can create nested models like so:

```
a_instance = ModelA.create(
                       modelBs: [ 
                            { modelCs: [{}]}                                    
                            ] 
                           ) 

a_instance.modelBs.first.modelCs.first._id # => BSON::ObjectId('5f0df5e063067000824541b5')
```